# Cannot run updated file from terminal of VSC, for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

So to make it very simple.

If I write print("Hello World") and run it on the RUN icon on top right corner it works perfectly fine.
And only then if I type in terminal   python hello.py   executes again just fine.

But if I change program to print("Hello to everybody") and I type in terminal   python hello.py   it executes the previous program and giving me Hello World on screen. But then again if I click on run icon and after correct execution repeat in terminal python hello.py, now it runs correctly.

Well I tried CTRL,SHift P, to change terminal and like select interpreter but couldn't figure out from which file is it trying to start program. And why is it correct after I use run icon.

Comment: don't use that Run button, use launch configs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saving the file after changing it? The Run button will run the code that is currently in the editor, while running it via `python` in the command line will run it from the saved file.